# How to show only last N lines in a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm creating a script to connect on a storage array and run a command.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("statvv -rw -iter 1")
for status in stdout:
    result = (status)
    print(result)
```

The output is this:

```
V90Z_10_3PAR05   t     0     0     0       0       0      0  0.00  0.00   0.0   0.0    0
V91A_10_3PAR05   r     0     0     0       0       0      0  0.00  0.00   0.0   0.0    -
V91A_10_3PAR05   w     0     0     0       0       0      0  0.00  0.00   0.0   0.0    -
V91A_10_3PAR05   t     0     0     0       0       0      0  0.00  0.00   0.0   0.0    0
--
           309   r  1577  1577        112637  112637         1.83  1.83  71.4  71.4    -
           309   w 20158 20158       1125017 1125017         1.49  1.49  55.8  55.8    -
           309   t 21736 21736       1237653 1237653         1.52  1.52  56.9  56.9    7
```

But I want to print only the last lines after the `--` without saving this to a file.

Comment: If you know how many lines to expect, you can skip the first N-M lines and print the remaining M lines. If you do not know, collect all lines into a list and then print the last M lines from the list. It is as easy as `print("\n".join(list(stdout)[-M:]))`.

Comment: If it's always the same number of lines, just pipe it through `tail` on the remote host. That way you don't transmit data you're not going to use.

Comment: Is Are those dashes part of `stdout`?

Comment: @DyZ Not a list, but a [bounded-length deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) (which the documentation describes as "similar to the tail filter in Unix") for efficiency.

Comment: Hi Prune. the dashes are part of stdout

Comment: @chepner1 No, a list. This data structure is called list in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the number of lines that you want to skip, then you could keep a counter and do something like this:

```
counter = 0 
MAX_COUNT = number_of_lines_you_want_to_skip
for status in stdout:
    if counter > MAX_COUNT:
        result = (status)
        print(result)
    else:
        counter ++
```

If you do not know the lines, you could keep reading until you see a `"--"` (which is what the snippet in your question looks like) and then print only those lines that came after the `"--"`

```
seen_dash_flag = false
for status in stdout:
    if status.startswith("--"):
        seen_dash_flag = true
    if seen_dash_flag:             
            result = (status)
            print(result)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Helps me a lot

Comment: Gald to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with statvv, but if you know the lines you want will always be after a line reading `'--'`, you can keep a boolean that tracks whether you've seen it:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("statvv -rw -iter 1")
final_status = False
for status in stdout:
    if final_status:
        print(status)
    elif status == '--':
        final_status = True
```

Comment: Thanks ryanmrubin